# required field validatior disables fileuplad asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am writing `asp.net` project using `C#`. The page consists of `text-boxes`, `file-uploader` with possibility to choose multiple files and this is done with `jQuery`, and also required field validator and submit button.

The problem is when I click the button when one or more textboxes are empty the validators get  error that field is empty, but the fileupload gets disabled.
So I want to create my own required field validator with javascript.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you given the right validation groups??

Comment: I set the validators and the submit button belong to one validation group. The file-uploader doesn't belong to any group because it hasn't this property. But the problem is still occuring, the fileuploader gets disabled(